# Сохранение таймера после закрытия приложения

Tags: ios, swift, мобильные-приложения

Как мне реализовать одну вещь, есть таймер, и кнопки управления, старт, пауза, стоп, при выходе приложения таймер сбрасывается, как сделать так, что бы если я даже выйду с приложения (не бэкграунд) и при повторном входе таймер накрутит время которое прошло?

Я думаю над алгоритмом сохранять таймер или дату и при входе сравнивать разницу, и уже выводить значение, я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать кодом, в поисках ничего подобного не нашел

Comment: Пробовали сохранять время начала таймера в user defaults?

Answer (score 0):

1. Сохраняйте значение Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate в UserDefaults при выходе
2. Затем сравнивайте при входе с новым значением Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, по разнице поймете, сколько прошло времени.